# Issue with AlertDialog being triggered by a button

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have an alert dialogue appear after I click a button but clicking the button doesn't do anything for some reason. I have it in the onPressed so I'm not sure why it isn't triggering. Also if I get this working will it work with Apple devices as well since this is a materials widget.

```
class AddButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, // align the row
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Test"),
                    content: Text("This is a test..."),
                    elevation: 24.0,
                  );
                },
                color: Colors.blue,
                splashColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 2,
              )
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `showDialog` method to make a dialog appear. Inside the builder callback, you then define the type of dialog you want ex. `AlertDialog`.

Example (from https://medium.com/@nils.backe/flutter-alert-dialogs-9b0bb9b01d28):

```
  //your method
  void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
          content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Your new code:

```
onPressed: () => _showDialog(context); // only pass context if you're in a stateless widget
```

Regarding Apple devices, instead of `AlertDialog`, you can use `CupertinoAlertDialog` if you're exclusively developing for iOS.

Comment: Thanks so much that solved my issue, and regarding the iOS question I want to make this a cross platform app so would materials support both platforms?